# Axis 2 migration from 1.5.3 to 1.7.9 issue

Tags: apache-axis

I am trying to upgrade my project from Axis 2 1.5.3 to Axis 2 1.7.9. I have removed all the jars belonging to Axis 2 1.5.3 version & replaced them with 1.7.9; but it is throwing the above erro

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.compare(Ljava/math/BigInteger;Ljava/lang/String;)I

This method is being called from model classes generated in Axis 1.5.3. I can see the method in class path but it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to regenerate model class using wsdl to java,  as there is changes in model structure in new axis version